# I could not resolve module because of the following error

Tags: react-native

error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `../../../.cache/typescript/2.6/node_modules/@types/prop-types` from `/../../../../../sample.js`: The module `../../../.cache/typescript/2.6/node_modules/@types/prop-types` could not be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue from import statement on sample.js page

import { array } from '../../../.cache/typescript/2.6/node_modules/@types/prop-types'